# Reference a variable value inside an @IBAction function from another class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, variables, ibaction

I'm trying to make a laundry timer app in Swift where the washer and drying will have different starting times, counting down to 0.

```
func updateTime() {
    ...
    var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = operationDuration - (currentTime - startTime)
    ...
   }
```

In the var elapsedTime I have operationDuration (how long the washer or dryer will take) and later on in the `@IBAction` func for pressing the "washer" button I have

```
let operationDuration == 1800
```

However I am getting an error the the updateTime func that

> 'operationDuration' is not defined.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

edit:

Here is my `washerButtonPress` code:

```
@IBAction func washerButtonPress(sender: AnyObject) {

        // TODO: start 30 minute countdown

        if !timer.valid {

            var operationDuration = 1800

            let aSelector:Selector = "updateTime"
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target:    self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        }
```

And how I'm trying to call it in my `func updateTime()`

```
var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = washerButtonPress.operationDuration - (currentTime - startTime)
```

and it returns `'(AnyObject) -> ()' does not have a member named 'operationDuration'`

I apologize for not knowing much but I'm pretty new to this

Answer (score 0):

If this is merely a constant, you can declare it as a global variable.

```
let kOperationDuration = 1800

class Washer {
    ...

    @IBAction func washerButtonPress(sender: AnyObject) {
        if !timer.valid {
            let aSelector:Selector = "updateTime"
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target:    self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Then in the Dryer class you can reference the constant.

```
class Dryer {
    ...

    func updateTime() {
        ...
        var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = kOperationDuration - (currentTime - startTime)
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Keith, thanks for that. I've tried playing around with what you have suggested and still can't get it to work. I've posted what my code looks like more in depth so maybe you could find the issue that still exists?

Comment: Changed my answer a little.